# pwrstatd eating 100% cpu

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments

Fan blasted on one of my dev boxes today. I ran **top** as all i was doing was slack and vscode and saw this line:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1251 root      20   0   10460   2108   1976 R 100.0  0.0  21:17.81 pwrstatd
```

So i looked up the process and it's something to do with being attached to a UPS, which this box is not, it's just connected to a powerbar because it's just a spare dev machine.

However I'm concerned because it looks like it was pinned at 100% a long time.

What can I do about it?

Comment: you can force it to stop, using `kill -9 1251` (`1251` is the current PID of `pwrstatd`, `-9` option is here to force the daemon to stop itself); let your CPU running at maximum isn't a good idea

Comment: That doesn't seem like a permanent solution. I'm concerned because other devs might reboot the machine while they work. can i just remove it's package?

Comment: you can look on `pwrstatd` code using `which pwrstatd` (it would probably return `/usr/bin/pwrstatd`, but confirm it), and control his code -> it's possible that it's a cryptominer malware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this myself, found that the USB cable that was being used to monitor my CyberPower UPS was lose. Fixing the connection caused the process to stop spinning, it was a in a tight loop trying to measure the outcome of select on some file descriptor spinning a CPU core.

Comment: While I am plugged into a cyberpower for power, i'm not connected to it by usb at all with this station

Comment: i know i'm pretty late on this, but this is the correct answer and fixed my issue.