# Upgrade to 21.10 brings 15-20° CPU temp increase

Tags: upgrade, cpu, temperature, 21.10

Last Saturday night, I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10. In reviewing my logs, I've noticed that immediately upon my upgrade, and lasting since, my PC's CPU temp baseline has jumped 15-20°. See charts from Friday, Saturday, and Sunday below, for comparison. I'd love to know if anyone has any thoughts on what might be going on.

[image: Friday]
[image: Saturday]
[image: Sunday]

Device specs: AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 64 GB RAM. I'm happy to provide any other info that might be helpful. I pull CPU temp with a script that runs every 5 minutes and reads the Tctl value from sensors.

UPDATE WITH MORE INFORMATION:

I've confirmed that pwrstatd was what was causing the high temps, and I feel like a complete dope for not checking sooner. Every day since I upgraded to 21.10, pwrstatd has been, as of my morning logs, either 93.8% or 100% CPU usage. I killed it yesterday afternoon, and here's what my temp graph looked like from this morning:
[image: Friday-update]

After I killed the daemon, I tried running "pwrstatd --help" just to get some more info on it, but that generated a segmentation fault. After I rebooted, the daemon no longer seems to be running. If anyone knows what my next steps should be, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: On my 20.04 Ubuntu test server I ran a 20.04 desktop VM and then a 21.10 desktop VM. After some settling time (less than 2 minutes) Processor package temperatures, Package Watts, and busyness, as observed on the host server, were the same between the two versions.

Comment: Doesn't Tctl have an offset? And maybe that offset changed by 15 degrees. Do you have access to any old and new Tdie data? From what I have read, there is no offset on Tdie.

Comment: @DougSmythies I won't have saved any old Tdie numbers, but I'll switch my logging to Tdie to avoid the offset problem as soon as I'm able. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Well, now I'm back to being confused, I'm afraid. I've been watching Psensor most of the morning, and Tctl and Tdie are running arm-in-arm. In case it's helpful at all, here's a snapshot of my sensors output:
<Oops, I can't paste it, it's too long.>

Comment: Trying again, temps only:

nouveau-pci-0800
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +52.0°C

nct6798-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
SYSTIN:                 +39.0°C
CPUTIN:                 +42.5°C
AUXTIN0:                +15.5°C
AUXTIN1:                -62.0°C
AUXTIN2:                +12.0°C
AUXTIN3:                +31.0°C
SMBUSMASTER 0:          +59.5°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +59.4°C  
Tdie:         +59.4°C  
Tccd1:        +58.8°C

Comment: Very interesting. Suggesting there is no offset involved with Tctl. I already upvoted the question. I use intel processors, don't know to to help further. Do you observe some sort of constant load that might explain the heat?

Comment: There's been no change in my use of the device, nor any indication that things are going on behind the scenes since the upgrade. I should say, FWIW, that I'm more interested in what's happening than worried. Also, I just realized I neglected to include my motherboard in the specs. It's an ASRock B550M Pro4.

Comment: My guess, and it is only a guess, it that previously it was actually reading the thermister at CPUIN and calling it Tctl. Actual on processor temperature readings for AMD processors is fairly new, so maybe the "hooks" for doing so were there but not actually used before. Observe that the difference is 16.9 degrees.

Comment: I've kept Psensor running for the weekend, and in looking at the chart it makes, what I'm seeing is that CPUIN reads a relatively level temperature with no peaks and valleys to speak of, but instead long ranges of plateaus that sometimes go up and down. Tctl and Tdie continue to run identically with shapes that look much more like my graphs above. I, too, can do nothing but guess, but I think whatever I'm measuring is the temperature I've always been measuring, it's just for some reason higher now.

Comment: More detailed examination of this issue after time reveals that this thread may be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187015/pwrstatd-eating-100-cpu